# How to retrieve specific value from firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am retrieving username from firebase database through searchview in my application. It is giving me the output. But the problem is that i am showing a message in toast "User not found" which should be displayed whenever the username is not available in database. But it is showing it both the times whether the username is available or not. I don't know how to fix it.
Here is my code:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    databaseref = databaseReference.child("usernames");

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new 
android.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(final String query) {

            if(CheckNetwork.isInternetAvailable(Search.this))
            {
                databaseref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                         for(DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                      {

                           name = data.getKey().toString();
                           pic = data.child("image").getValue(String.class);
                           id = data.child("id").getValue(String.class);

                             if(query.equals(name)) {

                                 textView.setText(name);


 Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(pic).fit().centerCrop().into
(imageView);
                             }
 else {
 Toast.makeText(Search.this, "No user found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                             }

                         }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

            }
            else {
 Toast.makeText(Search.this,"No internet 
 Connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            return true;
        }
```

Here is my database image: [image]

Answer (score 0):

You're not yet filtering the list of users by username:

```
databaseref.child(query).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       name = dataSnapshot.getKey().toString();
       pic = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue(String.class);
       id = dataSnapshot.child("id").getValue(String.class);
```

You'll note that I removed the loop, since in this case the listener is attached to a specific location: the node of the user whose name/key you entered in the search box.

Instead of a specific value, if you want to filter the users whose name/key **starts with** what is in the search box, you need a database query:

```
databaseref.orderByKey().startAt(query).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
           name = userSnapshot.getKey().toString();
           pic = userSnapshot.child("image").getValue(String.class);
           id = userSnapshot.child("id").getValue(String.class);
```

Comment: It didn't worked for me. It sets the username in textview both the times whether the username is available or not in database.
Anyhow i have found the solution :)

Comment: I gave two snippets. Which one doesn't work? Did you step through the code?

Comment: Don't know about the second one but the first one didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

when you entered the value in the search box now you specified the node so no need for looping the screenshot value is equivalent to the value you are looking for so, you can directly say:
      `dataSnapshot.child("image")getValue(String.class)`

Answer (score 0):

For your current code the problem is you are toasting "user not found" before completing parsing of all snapshots. eg: if your user is the 2nd snapshot your code will show "user not found" for the 1st snapshot without checking 2nd one. So you can change it by using a boolean set to true if found and check that boolean after the for loop. Like:

```
Boolean userFound = false;

for(DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                  {
                       name = data.getKey().toString();
                       pic = data.child("image").getValue(String.class);
                       id = data.child("id").getValue(String.class);
                         if(query.equals(name)) {
                             textView.setText(name);
                             userFound = true;
                             Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(pic).fit().centerCrop().into(imageView);
                         }

                     }
 if(!userFound){
                Toast.makeText(Search.this, "No user found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

also for a better solution you dont have to parse all the users , try @Frank van Puffelen answer.
You can go to the child directly by `databaseRef.child("query");`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution :)

```
databaseref.orderByKey().equalTo(query).addValueEventListener(new 
ValueEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

           for(DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                            name = data.getKey().toString();
                            pic = data.child("uri").getValue(String.class);
                            id = data.child("id").getValue(String.class);
              }

     if(query.equals(name)) {

     textView.setText(name);

 Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(pic).fit().centerCrop().into
 (imageView);
           }
     else {
 Toast.makeText(Search.this, "No user found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }

         }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: This `databaseref.orderByKey().equalTo(query)` is just a slower version of `databaseref.child(query)`. The only other difference is that yours will require you to loop over the result.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen but databaseref.child(query) is not working for me as i said earlier. Can you please check it out what is the problem?

Comment: The code I shared that uses `atabaseref.child(query).addValueEventListener(` gives the exact same result as what you have here. The only difference it that the `ValueEventListener` is more efficient (since it doesn't require a query) and less likely to fail when you start securing the data (since the listener is lower in the tree). If it doesn't work for you, show what you've tried with my first code snippet. There's likely a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Here what i have tried:
 
databaseref.child(query).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                              Log.d("TAG", dataSnapshot.toString());
                                name = dataSnapshot.getKey().toString();
                               pic = dataSnapshot.child("uri").getValue(String.class);
                                id = dataSnapshot.child("id").getValue(String.class);

And here is the LOG result for a value not present in our database:
TAG: DataSnapshot { key = kkkk, value = null }

Comment: It doesn't show in toast that this "kkkk" is not present in the database. It just it in textview.